# tensor product of a right and a left D-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I read that the tensor product of a right module $N$ and a left D-module $M$ can carry a right D-module structure, namely by acting as such, with evident notatoin

$$
\xi • (n\otimes m) = n • \xi\otimes m - n\otimes \xi • m
$$

the fact is checking that works

$$
[\xi,\psi] • (n\otimes m) = \xi • \psi • n \otimes m - \psi • \xi • n\otimes m
$$

is straightforward. But I thought that by definition, we should check that

$$
(\xi • \psi) • (n\otimes m) = \xi • (\psi • n\otimes m) 
$$

which is not correct. Isn't this relation one of the property to check ?

Comment: The tensor product $N\otimes_DM$ is at best an Abelian group, in general. More assumptions are necessary to exhibit a module structure like this

Comment: Can you please explain better the context? What is $D$ supposed to be?

Comment: @rschwieb I should have add some precision : suppose $D$ is a sheaf of differential operators on a regular manifold, so that the tensor  $N\otimes M$ is relative to the sheaf of regular functions and not relative to $D$

Comment: @egreg thank you for you response, see my previous comment

Comment: @user1611830 The "definition" you wrote down is for a left action not a right action!